# Web IDE SAPUI5 Routing between XML views not working?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I followed a guide on saps learning hub and used a tutorial aswell but still i am not able to making routing work. Am wondering if the installation of the Web IDE is something wrong?

component.js file

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
    "sap/ui/Device",
    "com/s5/mal/routingRouting/model/models"
], function(UIComponent, Device, models) {
    "use strict";

    return UIComponent.extend("com.s5.mal.routingRouting.Component", {

        metadata: {
            manifest: "json"
        },

        init: function() {
            // call the base component's init function
            UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);

            // set the device model
            this.setModel(models.createDeviceModel(), "device");

            this.getRouter().initialize();
        }
    });
});
```

main.view.xml file

```
<mvc:View controllerName="com.s5.mal.routingRouting.controller.Main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
    <App id="idApp" />
</mvc:View>
```

view1.view.xml

```
<mvc:View xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="com.s5.mal.routingRouting.controller.View1"
    xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <Page title="Title">
        <content>
            <Text text="View1" />
            <Button text="Next View" press="onPress" /> 
        </content>
    </Page>

</mvc:View>
```

view1.controller.js

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"
], function(Controller) {
    "use strict";

    return Controller.extend("com.s5.mal.routingRouting.controller.View1", {

        getRouter: function(){
            return sap.ui.core.UIComponent.getRouterFor(this);
        },
        onPress: function (oEvent){
            this.getRouter().navTo("View2");
        }
    });
});
```

manifest.json

```
       "routing": {
            "config": {
                "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                "viewPath": "com.s5.mal.routingRouting.view",
                "controlId": "idApp",
                "viewType": "XML",
                "controlAggregation": "pages",
                "transition": "slide"
            },
            "routes": [{
                "name": "View1",
                "pattern": "",
                "titleTarget": "",
                "greedy": false,
                "target": ["View1"]
            }, {
                "name": "View2",
                "pattern": "",
                "titleTarget": "",
                "greedy": false,
                "target": ["View2"]
            }, {
                "name": "notFound",
                "pattern": "",
                "titleTarget": "",
                "greedy": false,
                "target": ["notFound"]
            }],
            "targets": {
                "View1": {
                    "viewId": "View1", 
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "View1",
                    "viewLevel": 1
                },
                "View2": {
                    "viewId": "View2",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "View2",
                    "viewLevel": 2
                },
                "notFound": {
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "transition": "slide",
                    "clearAggregation": true,
                    "viewName": "NotFound"
                }
            }
        }
```

I can't seem to find out what is wrong even when i try other tutorials i end up with nothing. When i press my button i get no response. Like it never run, when i debug it, it is running right through my "onPress" button and no error on console log.

I simply want to make routing work, i have not made this happen yet.

Comment: What is the error you see ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your routes have empty pattern. If you navigate to route „view2“, its pattern is added to # in the url, then routing checks, which route matches the pattern => and finds „view1“

Leave view1 pattern empty, add patterns to your other routes.

Comment: Wow, my first time using asking a question in stackoverflow. I am surprised how fast i got an answer. Really not much info about this sapui5 but you sir are an angel. Thanks very much, used like more then 4 hours trying to fix this. Again thanks

Comment: I think the SAPUI5 documentation is actually pretty good about these basics: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5